# Formula for Is Current Fiscal Year Checkbox Based on Date

Tags: formula, formula-field

This is really just a placeholder to store the answer, for anyone else who needs to find this moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is below:

```
IF(
    IF( 
        (MONTH( Today() ) >= 6 && MONTH( Today() ) <= 12), 
        ((YEAR( Today() )+ 1)), 
        ((YEAR( Today() )) )
    )
    =
    IF( 
        (
            MONTH( AQB__DocumentedLegalDate__c ) >= 6 
            && MONTH( AQB__DocumentedLegalDate__c ) <= 12
        ), 
        ((YEAR( AQB__DocumentedLegalDate__c )+ 1)), 
        ((YEAR( AQB__DocumentedLegalDate__c )))
    ), 
    TRUE, 
    FALSE
)
```

Comment: There are a number of unecessary parenthesis here. Also, `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can _always_ be reduced to simply `<condition>`. That is to say, the outermost `IF()` is also completely unecessary.